# confusion with ternary and elvis

Tags: grails, groovy

i have the following code for handling default values when a lookup returns null

```
def user = User.find('admin') 
    return user?.address?user:null
```

this works as expected

however when using the Elvis operator like:

```
def user = User.find('admin') 
    return user?.address?:null
```

i get an exception thrown:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'true'         with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'com.code.User'
```

I was expecting Elvis to behave exactly like the ternary operator....?

thanks!

Comment: Other languages call ?: the "null-coalescing" operator. Only Groovy uses the in-joke name "Elvis" operator.

Comment: That's all well and good, but the question isn't about other languages, and as far as I can tell Groovy _always_ calls it the Elvis operator. In fact the phrase "null coalescing" doesn't appear [anywhere on their site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:groovy.codehaus.org+%22null+coalescing%22&tbs=li:1).

Comment: @Justin I added that info for anyone not familiar with what "Elvis op" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns `user` if the user is not null and `user.address` evaluates to `true`:

```
return user?.address?user:null
```

This returns `user.address` if the user is not null and `user.address` evaluates to `true`

```
return user?.address?:null
```

I assume `user.address` is a boolean?  So the second one is trying to return a boolean probably from a method you say returns a `User` in the definition

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you use

```
user?.address?user:null
```

it returns user if user has address. When you use

```
user?.address?:null
```

it tries to return **address** but not **user** instance.